# DHCP change requires reboot

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have a `static` IP set on my web-server.  When I change `static` to `dhcp` the server needs to be reboot for the changes to take effect.  Is there any way to make it so I can use `ifdown` and `ifup` to change it?

I know that it should work because I have had a server that was able to be changed from `static` to `dhcp` without rebooting.  I am just not sure if I am missing something.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.8.105.8
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.8.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 169.254.1.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

To set it to to `dhcp` I change the `iface eth0 inet static` to `iface eth0 inet dhcp`

I am also running into an issue of slow boot times when I declare `eth1` as another interface as it is.

Added info

```
default via 10.8.1.1 dev eth0 metric 100
10.8.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link 10.8.105.8
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.1.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 100
```

Comment: try this [I need to reset my computer's ip address to dhcp from static](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178970/i-need-to-reset-my-computers-ip-address-to-dhcp-from-static)

Comment: @Letizia the `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` ran but did not switch my network to a `dhcp` address when it is declared as `dhcp`

Comment: Could you describe what you did to change static to dhcp and post /etc/network/interfaces file content?

Comment: Did you use `ifdown eth0` and `ifup eth0`?

Comment: @Letizia Yes, that is what I normally use but sometimes I get this error `RTNETLINK answers: File Exists`  I have another post trying to solve that but they could very well deal with each other.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` posted is complete or there are other directive related to eth1? In particular is there a gateway definition for eth1?

Comment: @Letizia  that is the complete file.  I do not need to have a gateway on the eth1 since it is a local network communicating to a few devices.  I have heard a gateway conflict can cause slow boot issues.

Comment: Did you modify `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`?

Comment: @Letizia I have not.  Mine in empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17724/discussion-between-letizia-and-keith).

Answer (score 2):

What about using

**sudo ip addr flush dev eth0**

would that force the interface to pick up a new address?

Comment: It seemed to work.  I had to follow that command by a `ifdown eth0` and an `ifup eth0`.  It did however work so let me do some more situational testing on it.

Comment: Good! If it works, could you post `ip route` output after flush? I'm curious to know how it changes.